# PHP: Remove entry from array that contains

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I generate an array with URL's from a webpage with file_get_contents, that i want to remove entry's (key & value) from if they contain specific data.

For example:

```
[0] = 'http://somesite.com'
[1] = 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/55/file.pdf'
[2] = 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/56/file2.pdf'
[3] = 'javascript:void(0)'
[4] = 'mailto:info@somesite.com'
```

I want to remove the entry's

```
http://somesite.com
javascript:void(0)
mailto:info@somesite.com
```

Because i only need the URL's with the .pdf files.

How do i do that?

Comment: So, why don't you modify your initial uri retriever?

Answer (score 2):

You can use array filter for this (note this syntax works for php 5.3+)

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function ($a){ return preg_match ('/.pdf$/', $a); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help:

```
$sites[0] = 'http://somesite.com';
$sites[1] = 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/55/file.pdf';
$sites[2] = 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/56/file2.pdf';
$sites[3] = 'javascript:void(0)';
$sites[4] = 'mailto:info@somesite.com';

echo '<pre>'.print_r($sites, true).'</pre>';

//loop through your array of items/sites
foreach($sites as $key=>$value){
    //remove whitespace
    $value = trim($value);

    //get last 4 chars of value
    $ext = substr($value, -4, 0);

    //check if it is not .pdf
    if($ext != '.pdf'){
        //unset item from array
        unset($sites[$key]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($sites, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: May I request you to please [vote to undelete this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66013555/548225)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('http://somesite.com','http://someothersite.com/article/id/55/file.pdf','http://someothersite.com/article/id/56/file2.pdf','javascript:void(0)','mailto:info@somesite.com');

for($i=0; $i<=count($array)+1 ; $i++)
{
    if(end(explode('.',$array[$i])) != "pdf" )
    {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !!!!

```
$haystack = array (
'0' => 'http://somesite.com',
'1' => 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/55/file.pdf',
'2' => 'http://someothersite.com/article/id/56/file2.pdf',
'3' => 'javascript:void(0)',
'4' => 'mailto:info@somesite.com'
);

$matches  = preg_grep ('/pdf/i', $haystack);

//print_r ($matches);

foreach($matches as $k=>$v):
    echo $matches[$k]."<br/>";
endforeach;
```

**Documentation**
[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` is always an option, but if you want to remove specific values another good candidate is `array_diff`:

```
$remove = [
    'http://somesite.com',
    'javascript:void(0)',
    'mailto:info@somesite.com',
];

$filtered = array_diff($array, $remove);
```