# How do I use a regex in JavaScript to extract specific parts of a URL path?

Tags: javascript, regex

Right now, I'm trying to take a URL in this format:

`https://www.example.com/{section}/posts/{number}`

and get section and number. I need to do it with a regex; I cannot just break it into a parts array. I have tried:

```
var sect = myURL.match('https://www.example.com/[^/]+');
```

but I get as output `"https://www.example.com/{section}"`. I want to be able to get the `section` and the `number`. How do I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '^'`

Comment: Sorry typo, it should be `myURL.match(/^https?:\/\/www\.example\.com\/([^\/]+)\/posts\/(\d+)\/?$/)` and grab 2 capture groups`

Comment: thanks! is there any way to extract `section` and `number` separately?

Comment: @user11039951 why would you do it separate, it is in the capture groups....

Comment: It will be extracted separately from resulting array as `matches[1]` and `matches[2]`

Comment: @anubhava I mean a string variable I could set to ONLY grab `section` and another for only `number`?

Comment: @user11039951: Posted an answer below as it is difficult to post that much code in comments

Answer (score 3):

You can assign output of `matches` to multiple variables like this:

```js
var myURL = 'https://www.example.com/mysection/posts/1234';

[$0, sec, num] = myURL.match(/^https?:\/\/www\.example\.com\/([^\/]+)\/posts\/(\d+)\/?$/);

console.log(sec)
//=> mysection

console.log(num)
//=> 1234
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `https?:\/\/www\.example\.com\/`:
- `([^\/]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `/` and capture as group #1
- `\/posts\/`: Match `/posts/`
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits and capture as group #2
- `\/?$`: Match an optional trailing `/` before end

Comment: what precisely does the backslash do? Escape?

Comment: Yes that is for escaping special regex meta characters and we must escape `/` in Javascript regex

Comment: `const [sec, num] = myURL.match(/* ... */).slice(1);`

Comment: Yes @PeterSeliger a `slice` would also do the job of discarding first element of array

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to validate that the string is in fact a URL then just split it on forward slashes.

```js
var parts = `https://www.example.com/{section}/posts/{number}`.split(/\//);
console.log(parts[3]);
console.log(parts[5]);
```

If you "must" use regex match then:

```js
var matches = `https://www.example.com/{section}/posts/{number}`.match(/.*\/(?<section>[^\/]+)\/posts\/(?<number>.+)/);
console.log(matches.groups['section']);
console.log(matches.groups['number']);
```

Comment: I need to do it with regexes

Comment: @user11039951 Why?

Comment: because I just do

Comment: @user11039951 Oh okay, `.split()` accepts a regex literal instead of a string so I've updated my answer to use actual regex.

Answer (score 1):

One of course needs to retrieve this kind of path information just from an [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)'s [`pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) via e.g. the [*named capturing groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) of an accordingly written [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

For the provided example, the URL's pathname will be ...

```
/FOOBARBAZ/posts/987
```

.., thus a regex which uses named capture groups does look like ...

```
/\/(?<section>[^\/]+)\/posts\/(?<number>[^\/?#]+)/
```

... which reads like ...

- `\/(?<section>[^\/]+)` ... match a single slash then capture any sequence of characters that do not equal a slash, and name this capture group `section` ... then ...
- `\/posts` ... match a single slash and the sequence `posts` ... then ...
- `\/(?<number>[^\/?#]+)` ... match a single slash then capture any sequence of characters that are not equal to slash, question mark and hash, and name this capture group `number`.

```js
const {

  section,
  number

} = new URL('https://www.example.com/FOOBARBAZ/posts/987')
  .pathname
  .match(/\/(?<section>[^\/]+)\/posts\/(?<number>[^\/?#]+)/)
  .groups;

console.log({ section, number });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The same capturing approach without named groups does look like
this ...

```js
const [

  section,
  number

] = new URL('https://www.example.com/FOOBARBAZ/posts/987')
  .pathname
  .match(/\/([^\/]+)\/posts\/([^\/?#]+)/)
  .slice(1);

console.log({ section, number });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @user11039951 ... are there any questions regarding the approach?